# MySQL nodejs crash upon selecting data from big table

Tags: mysql, node.js, bigdata

I'm attempting to convert data from one database to the other but I'm getting some issues trying to get data from a big table, save it to an object and insert into another database. This is my code:

```
let sql;
let resultsToFetch = true;
while (resultsToFetch) {
  sql = `SELECT X FROM Y LIMIT ${index}, 1000`;
  DB1.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      resultsToFetch = false;
      throw err;
    } else if (result.length == 0) {
      resultsToFetch = false;
    } else {
      result.forEach(res => {
        const obj = {
          id: res.id,
          name: res.name
        };
        sql = "INSERT INTO X SET ?";
        DB2.query(sql, obj, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      });
    }
  });
  index += 1000;
}
```

I'm trying to use LIMIT so I'm not selecting all 6 million entries right away but I still get a Javascript heap out of memory error. I think I misunderstood something related to Node.js, but I'm not quite sure what it is. This is the error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[11256:000002A5D2CBB600]    22031 ms: Mark-sweep 1418.5 (1482.0) -> 1418.5 (1451.5) MB, 918.3 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[11256:000002A5D2CBB600]    22947 ms: Mark-sweep 1418.5 (1451.5) -> 1418.5 (1451.5) MB, 915.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000000B356525529 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [\index.js:~1] [pc=00000042DA416732](this=000000C326B04AD1 <Object map = 0000027D35B023B9>,exports=000000C326B04AD1 <Object map = 0000027D35B023B9>,require=000000C326B04A89 <JSFunction require (sfi = 00000229888651E9)>,module=000000C326B04A39 <Module map = 0000027D35B44F69>,__filename=000002298886B769 <String[52]\

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::DecodeWrite
 2: node_module_register
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray
 6: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting
 7: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayRandomIterator::UpdateOffsetFromIndex
 8: 00000042DA2843C1
```

Edit: @Grégory NEUT

```
let query = DB1.query("SELECT * FROM X");
let index = 0;
query
  .on("error", function(err) {
    // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
  })
  .on("fields", function(fields) {
    // the field packets for the rows to follow
  })
  .on("result", function(row) {
    // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
    DB1.pause();
    const obj = {
      id: row.id,
    };
    console.log(obj);
    const sql = `INSERT INTO X SET ?`;
    DB2.query(sql, obj, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      DB1.resume();
    });
    console.log(index);
    index++;
  })
  .on("end", function() {
    // all rows have been received
  });
```

Comment: Run this in batch, by recalling your method every x items

Comment: @Veve did you mean stream as the answer below?

Comment: Nope, but stream seems better indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how mysql driver is done in node.js but ***maybe*** it load everything and then limit the data. Or ***maybe*** 1000 entry are too much.

---

Anyway the soluce is to use [streams](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows)

```
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts');

query
  .on('error', function(err) {
    // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
  })
  .on('fields', function(fields) {
    // the field packets for the rows to follow
  })
  .on('result', function(row) {
    // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
    connection.pause();

    processRow(row, function() {
      connection.resume();
    });
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // all rows have been received
  });
```

---

So it will load in memory only the processed data at a time. Using it you will be sure that whatever the amount of data you have, you won't hit allocation failure.

Comment: This seems to get the job done but it's very slow, I posted the code below. Any advice?

Comment: I think it's normal that it takes a long time because you are making it synchronous (1 entry, 1 push, 1 entry, 1 push...). If you make it asynchronous it'll be faster, but you gotta handle the end of the insertions and the number of parallel requests.

Comment: Alright, I make a 'insert statement' string in the on('results') callback now which pause the execution each time it appends 1000 inserts to the 'insert statement' string then executes it and resumes - repeat until done. That seem to run 100x times faster.